# lambda expressions, parenthesis, and order of application

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am building a lambda applicator in Java, and I have uncovered a bit of misunderstanding.  Either my question at the bottom is what I am asking, or something in the build-up below is wrong.  Either way, I'd appreciate any insight.

So, `NOT` can be defined as

`λb.b (λxy.y) (λuv.u)`

If we allow

```
A1 = λb.b
B1 = (λxy.y)
C1 = (λuv.u)
```

Now NOT is `(A1 B1 C1)`

By order of operations, `B1` will be applied before `C1`
So let `Not1 = (A1 B1)`

`NOT` can now be rewritten as `(Not1 B1)` or `((A1 B1) C1)`.

When we apply the expression

`TRUE = (λdw.d)`

to `NOT`, we have

`((A1 B1) C1) TRUE`

Which, because `A1` is the identity function, is supposed to get us

`((TRUE B1) C1)`

... but why wouldn't we apply `B1` to `A1` first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding what $\lambda$-abstraction represents and are not considering its scope. First; your definition of $NOT$ is correct and $NOT$ is in normal form.

It is not true that $\lambda b. b\ (\lambda x y. y)\ (\lambda u v. u)$ is the same as $(A_1\ B_1\ C_1)$ and I give here two reasons why:

1. The body of $\lambda$-abstraction goes as far right as possible (after ".", until its enclosing brackets, in our case none) and therefore $\lambda b. b\ (\lambda x y. y)\ (\lambda u v. u)$ is a $\lambda$-abstraction with variable $b$ and body $b\ (\lambda x y. y)\ (\lambda u v. u)$. The string "$\lambda b. b$" in this case is not representing an identity expression, but is a part of the definition of $\lambda$-abstraction. Its $\lambda$ "belongs" to the whole $NOT$ expression. Written fully parenthesised, your expression for $NOT$ would be
   $$\biggl(\lambda b. \Bigl(\bigl(b\ (\lambda x y. y)\bigr)\ (\lambda u v. u)\Bigr)\biggr)$$
2. If it were in fact the same as $(A_1\ B_1\ C_1)$, this could reduce to $(B_1\ C_1)$ which could then reduce to $\lambda y. y$ which is identity (which is not $NOT$) and $\lambda$-expressions have at most one normal form.

The $NOT$ operator, when applied to some expression $X$ should reduce like this:
$$\bigl(\lambda b. b\ (\lambda x y. y)\ (\lambda u v. u)\bigr)\ X \rightarrow_\beta X\ (\lambda x y. y)\ (\lambda u v. u)$$

---

You can try your ideas and check existing examples with [pLam](https://github.com/sandrolovnicki/pLam) to help you build a similar tool by yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'm having a little trouble squaring that with [this document](https://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS03/alpi/lambda.pdf), in which `<expression> := <name>|<function>|<application>`, and 
"we adopt the convention that function application associates from the left, that is, the expression $E_1E_2E_3...E_n$ is evaluated applying the expressions as follows:
$(...((E_1E_2)E_3)...E_n)$".  Is my source document simply incorrect?

Comment: Oh, I see that they've hinted that every expression there is an application.  They don't clearly discuss the interplay between functions and applications, however.

Comment: The document looks correct. You can see that application is left associative in my answer also, where I fully parenthesised the body of $NOT$. In the document, “function” and “name” are what I and most other resources call “abstraction” and “variable”. Every lambda expression is either variable, abstraction or application. Does this clear your confusion?

Comment: @SandroLovnički Is it safe to say, then, that an abstraction on the left side will pull in every expression to the right if not blocked by parenthesis?  So ${\lambda}x.x (y) z (a) b (c) d (e)$ will become ${\lambda}x.(x (y) z (a) b (c) d (e))$?

Comment: @BenI. Yes, exactly :)

Comment: @SandroLovnički That made me feel so nice!  One more, if you don't mind. ${\lambda}x.x\ y\ {\lambda}g.g\ v$ would be ${\lambda}x.(x\ y\ {\lambda}g.(g\ v))$?

Comment: @BenI. Correct.